# Arel query where a value is between two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I'd like to write a query in ActiveRecord/Arel (without hard-coding the SQL) testing that a date is between two columns: e.g. `WHERE input_date BETWEEN some_table.column_1 AND some_table.column_2`. I've tried the following:

```
between_query = Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
  Time.zone.now,
  Arel::Nodes::And.new(
    [
      arel_table[:column_1],
      arel_table[:column_2]
    ]
  )
)
where(between_query)
```

but I get the error `Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError: Unsupported argument type: Time. Construct an Arel node instead.`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using a good old fashioned AR `where` statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to *Construct an Arel node instead*:

```
between_query = Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
  Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(Time.zone.now),
  Arel::Nodes::And.new(
    [
      arel_table[:column_1],
      arel_table[:column_2]
    ]
  )
)
where(between_query)
```

Comment: Also you can do it by `Arel.sql("'#{Time.zone.now}'")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `Time.zone.now` with some sort of SQL node.  If you just trying to see if the current time is between two columns, this should work:

```
between_query = Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
  Arel.sql('current_date'),
  Arel::Nodes::And.new(
    [
      arel_table[:column_1],
      arel_table[:column_2]
    ]
  )
)
where(between_query)
```

otherwise, if you are trying to pass in a variable time, instead of `Arel.sql('current_date')`, replace it with `Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(Time.zone.now.to_s(:db))`